# Button not responding to first click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am developing an android application and have a button which launches another activity. The button does not respond to the first click ,but respond to subsequent touches. The xml for the relevant button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bonePArenaplay"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bmainleaderboard"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arenabtnback"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowRadius="25"
    android:text="Play"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

The Java Code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
     {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    bonePArenaplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bonePArenaplay);

    bonePArenaplay.setOnClickListener(this);
      .....
     }      

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clickanim);
    Log.d("clicked", "called");
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.bonePArenaplay:

        bonePArenaplay.setAnimation(anim2);
        bonePArenaplay.startAnimation(anim2);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GenreActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Mode", 1);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
     ....
```

I am trying for an answer for over a week now and have looked at every answer on stackoverflow but all in vain

And this issue is replicated in every button in my application. Every Activity does not respond to first touch but does respond to subsequent touches. Any help is appreciated.

Some Solutions i have tried:-

1 The setonclicklistener is in oncreate

2 I have tried setting ontouchlistener to call onclicklistener still no effect

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or on a physical hardware device? It could be a fault of one or the other.

Comment: I am testing on a real device and the problem persists on other devices i have tried

Comment: Can you post the code for your `OnClickListener`?

Comment: have updated the question with the same

Comment: Anything in LogCat after first touch? I would comment out all the animation related code and try again to see if that is the problem here.

Comment: No output in the logcat whatsoever.I have actually added the animation so as to give a feedback that the button has been clicked

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:focusable="false"
```

the first click gives the button focus since it currently can't be focused.

Comment: In what method is your code snippet? In which class?

Comment: Have you also tried removing `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` or making it true?